# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host while connecting AX service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, iis

I am having a .net mvc application  which will be consuming AX services and displaying the data . The application is working fine when I running it from visual studio. But Its throwing the error "**An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host** "  once after I hosted in IIS. any clue.

Comment: Make sure to check authentication.  Also,  the machine on which  you developed and the machine you deployed are different and having different configs. Also, check event viewer and networks logs on server. Also,  check request response using fiddler tools. You question is to broad to answer having little knowledge of what's inside your app.  Make question understandable and also provide the details what you've tried

Comment: reset your iis by running this **resetiis** command from command promt and make your you are open command promt as administrator or check the port on which your AX service is running on IIS and check if another service is using the same port if yes it causes the problem hope it helps